# Visual Studio 2015 Regex Replace Not Working (Regex Match Working)

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to replace XML documentation comments in a large project that have been incorrectly using `<item></item>` instead of `<item><description></description></item>`. I figured that using the Visual Studio find and replace functionality would probably be the quickest way to do this. So, I came up with the following regex:

```
(?ixs)(?<=///.*<item\b[^>]*>)(?<description>[^\<]*?)(?=</\s*?item>)
```

In the "Find In Files" mode in Visual Studio 2015's Find and Replace functionality, the regex matches 249 lines in the project.

However, if I try to use "Find and Replace", and use `<description>${description}</description>` in the "Replace with" textbox, I get zero matches.

I tried using `$1`, `$2`, and `$+` instead of `${description}`, but in each case I get zero matches.

I also used a literal value `REPLACEMENT` in the "Replace with" textbox and it replaces all 249 lines with the word `REPLACEMENT`.

I tried this both in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 with the same result.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx), this should be the syntax for substituting the text. So why is it not working in Visual Studio?

> NOTE: The project I am trying this with is https://github.com/apache/lucenenet, in case anyone wants to test under the same conditions I am.

Environment:

- Windows 10 x64
- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (Update 3)

### Sample Input

```
/// For more examples, see the <see cref="Lucene.Net.Analysis"/> namespace documentation.
/// <para/>
/// For some concrete implementations bundled with Lucene, look in the analysis modules:
/// <list type="bullet">
///   <item>Common:
///       Analyzers for indexing content in different languages and domains.</item>
///   <item>ICU:
///       Exposes functionality from ICU to Apache Lucene.</item>
///   <item>Kuromoji:
///       Morphological analyzer for Japanese text.</item>
///   <item>Morfologik:
///       Dictionary-driven lemmatization for the Polish language.</item>
///   <item>Phonetic:
///       Analysis for indexing phonetic signatures (for sounds-alike search).</item>
///   <item>Smart Chinese:
///       Analyzer for Simplified Chinese, which indexes words.</item>
///   <item>Stempel:
///       Algorithmic Stemmer for the Polish Language.</item>
///   <item>UIMA:
///       Analysis integration with Apache UIMA.</item>
```

Comment: Did you try using `$1` back-reference while changing `(?<description>[^\<]*?)` to `([^\<]*?)`?

Comment: @revo - Yes, I tried that, too. I also tested the Regex with a home-brew Regex testing utility that correctly extracts the text into the default and first capturing group.

Comment: Do you confirm that the regex matches characters not a position?

Comment: Yes, it extracts the text out of the group and definitely matches it correctly. Or, did you mean something else by that?

Comment: Alright. Please also add a sample input.

Comment: @revo - I have added a sample

Comment: If you're simply talking about a search and replace in the development environment, why not simply make it in two steps - first replace `<item>` with `<item><description>` and then `</item>` with `</description></item>`?

Comment: @ClasG - Because there are several places where `<item><term>` are used to create tables, and other places where `<item><term></term><description><description><item>` are used as well.

Comment: I can be stubborn ;) How about `<item>(?!\s*<)` with `<item><description>` and `</item>(?!\s*<)` with `</description></item>`? Then it'll only replace if it isn't followed by another tag (sort of).

Comment: Maybe that would work in this case. But it doesn't answer the bigger question of how do I consistently do find/replaces using regex in this more than 900,000 line solution.

Comment: I can't reproduce the same issue. (RegexBuddy v4, Visual Studio 2012-2015 IDE engine)

Comment: This is still broken in Visual Studio 2019. I think VS passes the search string to a different function when replaceall is called, and it may be using a different regex flavor. This seems to happen with named capture groups.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the problem in VS2012. Had to change regex to account for newlines (`([^\<]|\r\n)*?` instead of just `[^\<]*?`). It works when replacing items one by one, but does nothing when you want to replace all. Could be a bug.

This works though (not using lookaheads and lookbehinds):

Find: `<item>(([^\<]|\r\n)*)`
Replace with: `<item><description>$1</description>`

Comment: I've noticed this, as well. And it is still present in the latest update to VS 2017. When using look-ahead or look-behind structures in the "Find what" text, "Replace All" does nothing. Instead I have to click "Replace" for each instance - worse, it often skips replacement for alternating instances, requiring several passes over each file until there is only one instance left - which often fails to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue (Find All and Replace All not working but Replace working in a given file) with the regular Find & Replace in Visual Studio 2015.  I was performing a find in "Selection": I selected the text I wanted to run the REGEX replace over, pressed Ctrl + H for the Find & Replace tool and started typing in the REGEX (at this point Visual Studio started highlighting text within the selection).  When I then clicked "Replace All" or "Find All" no results were found but I found out that if I selected the text again with the Find & Replace tool still open then Find All and Replace All started working again!

This seems like a bug as the text was already selected and became deselected as I was writing my REGEX (even though it no longer had the usual selection background colour, it did still appear to have a background highlight colour when compared to the rest of the file to indicate that it was still selected even though Find & Replace acted as though it wasn't selected!).

I don't know whether this answers your question directly as I'm not sure what mode you were using for "Find In", but if it was "Selection" then this could be the issue.